# TWebBrowser, OleObject и его свойства

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, необходимо написать программу которая берет текст с загруженной в браузере страницы. Вот как я ее решил. `var
a:string;
begin
WebBrowser1.Navigate('Сайт');
a:=WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.documentElement.innerText;
Memo1.Lines.Add(a);
End.`

И все хорошо работает только программа выдает ошибку: 
Access violation at address 0045b167 in module 'Progect1.exe'. Read fo address 00000000.

Как убрать данную ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это весь код программы? если да - то скорее всего документ еще не загружен а вы пытаетесь получить его текст. Там есть событие у WebBrowser1 которое выполняется после того как документ прогружен, вот туд аи нада вешать

```
  a:=WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.documentElement.innerText;
  //кстати я бы сюда еще  добавил Memo1.Clear(). -очищаем. Хотя по вашему функционалу может вам ето и не нада 
``Memo1.Lines.Add(a);
```

Comment: Да, как сказал @Ale_x, надо вешать на *OnNavigateComplete2*(D2010)